# Are nans counted when using the len() function?

Tags: python

I am trying to count the length of two series, and it seems to not count some nans within both series. I am curious to what len() counts and doesn't count.  I'd love to see some different examples of len() not picking up nans, infs, or whatever else it might skip over.

Comment: What is it that you're applying `len()` to?

Comment: `len()` doesn't skip over anything. `nan` is still an object in the list.

Comment: Can't you fill a list with nans and see for yourself?

Comment: Might need to reread my question once more.  I am trying to apply len() to two separate series. @MartijnPieters I think you are right, could it possibly skipped over an "inf"?

Comment: @tylerswright: no, not for standard types. Please include a [mcve] to demonstrate the actual problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 5):

If we're talking about applying `len()` to a list, then the values don't matter: all elements will be included in the count. This includes `None`, NaNs etc.

If we're talking about applying `len()` to something other than a list, then we'd need to know what that something is.

Comment: Makes sense, I am working with two series.